# MYSQL - max_connections

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql installed `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.37, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`. I need to increase the `max_connection` parameter from the default 150 permanently.
I had a look at all the answers posted on stackoverflow and can't seem to find a solution that works.
The only place I was able to find a glimpse of this is parameter is in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` but in there `max_connections` parameter seem to be commented out. I tried changing it removing the # and restarted the server, didn't work. the `mysql.cnf` file under `/etc/mysql` does not contain any parameters as well, just

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
```

Comment: [Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html). There is more than one option file. Find actual one and edit it (if the parameter is absent in it then add a row into according section). Alternatively you may set this setting in the service starting command line.

Comment: can you please give me a bit of guidance on setting this in the service starting command line, or maybe some documentation for mysql/unix i can refer to